# How to mock an object with Jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, mocking, jasmine, stubbing

On my DI setup I have a singleton class that has a couple of functions which I would like to disable when testing.

In some other frameworks / languages I would provide a mock of that object whose implementation of the functions is empty.

I'd like to do something like

```js
TestBed.configureTestModule({
    imports: […],
    providers: [
        { provide: MyClass, useValue: spyAllFunctions(MyClass).and.stub() }
    ]
})
```

I've already taken a look at `spyAllFunctions` but doesn't get me quite there (or I am misusing it), for now I am just providing the stub myself, but I wonder if there's a better way than

```js
{
    provide: MyClass, deps: [MyClassDependency], useFactory: (dep) => ({
      method1: () => { },
      method2 () => { }
    })
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think you are looking for the createSpyObj function (https://jasmine.github.io/2.5/introduction)

Comment: Would you mind providing me with a snippet on how to achieve what I intend? What string should I pass in as first parameter? Are all the spyes stubbed with `() => {}` or alike?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enno.void is right, I think you need `createSpyObj` function.

```
let mockMyClass: any;

// first string is the name of the class (can be anything), second argument is
// an array of strings of methods you want to be able to mock
mockMyClass = jasmine.createSpyObj('my-class', ['method1', 'method2']);
.....
TestBed.configureTestModule({
    imports: […],
    providers: [
        { provide: MyClass, useValue: mockMyClass }
    ]
})
```

Check this [link](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#testing-with-a-spy) out.